# Error while installed tensor flow on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I created my own virtual environment for my work in python anaconda. I installed tensor flow and checked my version as  `tensorboard   2.3.1  pypi_0    pypi`. However, when I am trying to import the following libraries

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
```

But even after installing tensor flow and with an upgraded version, I am getting the following error

```
`ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rp603\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-c947233989bd> in <module>
----> 1 from keras.models import Sequential
      2 from keras.layers import Dense
      3 from keras.layers import LSTM

~\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      4 except ImportError:
      5     raise ImportError(
----> 6         'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
      7         'Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`')
      8 

ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`
```

Any help on how to solve this issue and install using anaconda? Thanks in advance

The output of `conda list` on my environment as follows

```
(ML) C:\Users\rp603>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\rp603\Anaconda3\envs\ML:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.2.0                     eigen
absl-py                   0.11.0           py37haa95532_0
aiohttp                   3.7.2            py37h2bbff1b_1
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
argh                      0.26.2                   py37_0
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py37he774522_1
astor                     0.8.1                    py37_0
astroid                   2.4.2                    py37_0
async-timeout             3.0.1                    py37_0
async_generator           1.10             py37h28b3542_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     20.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
autopep8                  1.5.4                      py_0
babel                     2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0
bcrypt                    3.2.0            py37he774522_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.2.1                      py_0
blinker                   1.4                      py37_0
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37h2bbff1b_1003
ca-certificates           2020.10.14                    0
cached-property           1.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
cachetools                4.1.1                      py_0
certifi                   2020.6.20          pyhd3eb1b0_3
cffi                      1.14.3           py37hcd4344a_2
chardet                   3.0.4           py37haa95532_1003
click                     7.1.2                      py_0
cloudpickle               1.6.0                      py_0
colorama                  0.4.4                      py_0
cpuonly                   1.0                           0    pytorch
cryptography              3.2.1            py37hcd4344a_1
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
diff-match-patch          20200713                   py_0
docutils                  0.16                     py37_1
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
flake8                    3.8.4                      py_0
freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0
future                    0.18.2                   py37_1
gast                      0.2.2                    py37_0
google-auth               1.23.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
google-pasta              0.2.0                      py_0
gpytorch                  1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.31.0           py37he7da953_0
h5py                      3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      2.10                       py_0
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0
importlib-metadata        2.0.0                      py_1
importlib_metadata        2.0.0                         1
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254
intervaltree              3.1.0                      py_0
ipykernel                 5.3.4            py37h5ca1d4c_0
ipython                   7.19.0           py37hd4e2768_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
isort                     5.6.4                      py_0
jedi                      0.17.1                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0
joblib                    0.17.0                     py_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                3.2.0                      py_2
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py37_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
keras                     2.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
keyring                   21.4.0                   py37_1
kiwisolver                1.3.0            py37hd77b12b_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37he774522_0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf               3.13.0.1             h200bbdf_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h33f27b4_0
libtiff                   4.1.0                h56a325e_1
libuv                     1.40.0               he774522_0
lz4-c                     1.9.2                hf4a77e7_3
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  3.3.3            py37haa95532_0
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_1
matplotlib                3.3.2                         0
matplotlib-base           3.3.2            py37hba9282a_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
mistune                   0.8.4           py37hfa6e2cd_1001
mkl                       2020.2                      256
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft                   1.2.0            py37h45dec08_0
mkl_random                1.1.1            py37h47e9c7a_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multidict                 4.7.6            py37he774522_1
nbclient                  0.5.1                      py_0
nbconvert                 6.0.7                    py37_0
nbformat                  5.0.8                      py_0
nest-asyncio              1.4.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ninja                     1.10.1           py37h7ef1ec2_0
notebook                  6.1.4                    py37_0
numpy                     1.19.4                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.19.2           py37ha3acd2a_0
numpydoc                  1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
oauthlib                  3.1.0                      py_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openssl                   1.1.1h               he774522_0
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0
packaging                 20.4                       py_0
pandas                    1.1.3            py37ha925a31_0
pandoc                    2.11                 h9490d1a_0
pandocfilters             1.4.3            py37haa95532_1
paramiko                  2.7.2                      py_0
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py37_1001
pillow                    8.0.1            py37h4fa10fc_0
pip                       20.2.4           py37haa95532_0
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0
prometheus_client         0.8.0                      py_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.8                      py_0
protobuf                  3.13.0.1         py37ha925a31_1
psutil                    5.7.2            py37he774522_0
ptyprocess                0.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0
pycodestyle               2.6.0                      py_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pydocstyle                5.1.1                      py_0
pyflakes                  2.2.0                      py_0
pygments                  2.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    py37_0
pylint                    2.6.0                    py37_0
pynacl                    1.4.0            py37h62dcd97_1
pyopenssl                 19.1.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py37_1
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py37he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_1
python                    3.7.9                h60c2a47_0
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
python-jsonrpc-server     0.4.0                      py_0
python-language-server    0.35.1                     py_0
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.7.0               py3.7_cpu_0  [cpuonly]  pytorch
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0
pywin32                   227              py37he774522_1
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py37_1001
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py37_0
pyyaml                    5.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     19.0.2           py37ha925a31_1
qdarkstyle                2.8.1                      py_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 1.0.1                      py_0
qtconsole                 4.7.7                      py_0
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0
rope                      0.18.0                     py_0
rsa                       4.6                        py_0
rtree                     0.9.4            py37h21ff451_1
scikit-learn              0.23.2           py37h47e9c7a_0
scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.11.0                     py_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                50.3.1           py37haa95532_1
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.15.0           py37haa95532_0
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0
sortedcontainers          2.2.2                      py_0
sphinx                    3.2.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.3                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4                      py_0
spyder                    4.1.5                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            1.9.4                    py37_0
sqlite                    3.33.0               h2a8f88b_0
tensorboard               2.3.0              pyh4dce500_0
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0
tensorflow                2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py37_1
terminado                 0.9.1                    py37_0
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0
tk                        8.6.10               he774522_0
toml                      0.10.1                     py_0
torchaudio                0.7.0                      py37    pytorch
torchvision               0.8.1                  py37_cpu  [cpuonly]  pytorch
tornado                   6.0.4            py37he774522_1
traitlets                 5.0.5                      py_0
typed-ast                 1.4.1            py37he774522_0
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                       0
typing_extensions         3.7.4.3                    py_0
ujson                     4.0.1            py37ha925a31_0
urllib3                   1.25.11                    py_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_3
watchdog                  0.10.3                   py37_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py37_0
wheel                     0.35.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py37haa95532_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
windrose                  1.6.8              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
xlrd                      1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
yapf                      0.30.0                     py_0
yarl                      1.5.1            py37he774522_0
zeromq                    4.3.2                ha925a31_3
zipp                      3.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
zstd                      1.4.5                h04227a9_0
```

Comment: Hi, could you share your complete environment (`conda list`), so that we can try to reproduce?

Comment: I shared the complete environment. Please see the updated version of the question.

Comment: The error message is probably not giving you the right direction. Perhaps their is a problem with a tensorflow dependency. I would recommend trying `conda update --all` or conda update tensorflow=2.3.1` to check the dependencies based on conda recipes.

Comment: The version error is misleading, it happens because tensorflow fails to import, you should read this part and folllow the instructions " Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors "

Comment: @RomainReboulleau after using 'conda update --all'. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy could you please elaborate. I could not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Simple, the problem is that tensorflow fails to import (just import it to see), and you should fix that problem.

Comment: Why install Tensorflow through pip, instead of Conda?

Answer (score 1):

Your `tensorflow` is being imported from

```
File "C:\Users\rp603\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py"
```

which is a python 3.7 installation that is different from your anaconda one. You are likely seeing issues because of this.

Uninstall any python installation other than the anaconda one, you should not need them anymore. Also remove `C:\Users\rp603\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37` after uninstalling that python version to make sure no residues remain that can cause issues

Comment: How to uninstall python other than anaconda one? any quick method

Comment: I don't know of any "quick" method. Simply go to Windows Settings->Apps&features and uninstall the non-Anaconda pythons